# Microsoft Information Protection (MIP) downgraded sqlite3 version from mip 1.12.101

Tags: sqlite, microsoft-information-protection, mip-sdk

Recently my team have upgraded the MIP library in our Android application to version 1.12.101 and we ran a security scan for any potential vulnerabilities and we found out that the sqlite3 library bundled in mip is downgraded from version 3.34.1 to 3.1.0 introducing many old/patched vulnerabilities. This change is not mentioned in MIP release notes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/information-protection/develop/version-release-history
Afterwards we checked the latest MIP version 1.13.161 but it still has the old sqlite3 version.

Not sure if Microsoft engineers are checking this channel or we have missed any other information/announcement for this downgrade but my team is wondering for the reasons of downgrading and if they are any plans to update sqlite3 again in the next versions. Also we are wondering if the vulnerabilities coming with the old version of sqlite3 3.1.0 are impacting the functionality of MIP as for now we are only using it to AIP labels.